# Simple question about holonomy and the orbifold $C^2/Z_{2}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This query is from Gubser's TASI lectures on [Special Holonomy in string theory and M-theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0201114).

There is a detailed description in the first lecture, of the orbifold $C^2/Z_2$ and I think I understand it generally, except for the conclusion.

The smooth version of the orbifold is described by

$$z_1^2 + z_2^2 + z_3^2 = \epsilon^2$$

where $\epsilon$ is real.

Writing $z_j = x_j + i y_j$ for $x_j, y_j \in \mathbb{R}$ and $j = 1, 2, 3$, this splits into two equations:

$$\vec{x}^2 - \vec{y}^2 = \epsilon^2, \qquad \vec{x}\cdot\vec{y} = 0$$

Then the author describes how for $\vec{x}^2 + \vec{y}^2 = \epsilon^2$, one gets a 2-sphere $S^2$ with radius $\epsilon$. The cotangent space $T^\star S^2$ of this 2-sphere is a fibration of $\textbf{R}^2$ over $S^2$ ($\textbf{R}^2$ is the space of 1-forms on the 2-sphere, as shown in the lecture notes.)

But now, the conclusion is that $\textbf{C}^2/\textbf{Z}_2$ is a *cone* over $S^3/\textbf{Z}_2$. Where did the $S^3$ come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really weirdly written, but the statement that $\mathbb{C}^2/\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a cone over $S^3/\mathbb{Z}_2$ doesn't follow from what's written in these notes at all.

In general, an (infinite) cone over a space $X$ is obtained by forming $X\times [0,\infty)$ and then collapsing $X\times\{0\}$ to a point. That $\mathbb{R}^n$ is such a cone over its unit sphere $S^{n-1}$ is easily seen by e.g. choosing polar coordinates, where the collapsed point is the origin $r=0$, for which all the possible angles have been identified to give the same point.

So $\mathbb{C}^2 \cong \mathbb{R}^4$ is a cone over $S^3$, and therefore also $\mathbb{C}^2/\mathbb{Z}_2$ over $S^3/\mathbb{Z}_2$ since the fixed point of the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action on $\mathbb{C}^2$ is precisely the origin/tip of the cone and therefore doesn't mess with this cone structure.

Comment: Thanks @ACuriousMind. Do you have a better reference or references for such kinds of mathematical results?